# Property of functions like $\sin{2x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow[-1,1]$ be a function twice differentiable such that
$$f(0)^2+f'(0)^2=4.$$

Prove or give a counterexample that for all such function $f$, there exists $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c)+f''(c)=0$.

The function $f(x)=\sin{2x}$ satisfies the conditions and the result. But how can we prove the result for all $f$ or refute it? I really can't see any counterexample. I tried to observe the function $g(x)=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$ (observe that $g'(x)=2f'(x)[f(x)+f''(x)]$) and I thought that I proved the result finding a point that satisfies $g'(c)=0$, but I realize that maybe $f'(c)=0$, and from that point I couldn't prove anything useful.

Comment: "But how can we prove?": prove what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust prove that there exists a $c\in\Bbb R$ with $f(c)+f''(c)=0$, obviously

Comment: @vrugtehagel: this was already proven by the OP. So what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think that nothing was proved.

Comment: @Harry49 for $2 (\arctan{\pi x})/\pi$ also exists such $c$

Comment: @math_pi: does one really need to prove $\sin^2(2\cdot0)+(\sin'(2\cdot0))^2=4$ and $\sin2c+\sin''2c=0$ for some $c$ ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust this is just an example of a function that satisfies the conditions of the problem but doesn't prove that it's true for every such fucntion $f$.

Comment: @math_pi: there is no "for all" anywhere, hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, we start with $f(0)=0, f'(0)=2$.  We should be able to make $|f''(x)|$ big enough so we don't overrun $[-1,1]$  We need $f''(0) \neq 0$ or $c=0$ gets us.  We can patch together polynomials to do what we need as long as we keep the first derivatives smooth.  So take $$f(x)=\begin {cases} \frac 12+2x &-.1 \le x \lt .1\\ 0.4+4x-10x^2 &.1 \le x \lt .2\\0.8& x \ge .2\end {cases}$$  I think that does what you need and will leave the negative end to you.

Comment: What is the second derivative at $x=0.2$?

Comment: @math_pi:  I thought I had it smooth enough, but you are right.  The idea is sound.  I have to leave now and can't patch it up.  There is a problem at $0.1$ as well.  You can also use $e^{(-1/x)} to smooth things out.

Answer (score 0):

Choose 
$$f(x)=\frac{2e^2}{\sqrt17}\cdot e^{-1/(x+1/2)}$$
for $x>-1/2$ and $0$ else. Then any $c\leq -1/2$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: Nice, but this is another example of a function that satisfies the condition. I want a function such that doesn't exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ for wich $f(c)+f''(c)=0$, to be a counterexample, or to prove that for every such function $f$ exists such $c$.

Comment: Guy, I think that you gave a counterexample. If we define the function to be symetric to $x=-1/2$ we have a function such that doesn't exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ for wich  $f(c)+f′′(c)=0$

Comment: Easier: $f(x)=x^4/24+2$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe:  but the values are not contained in $[-1,1]$

Comment: A possible duplicate target (with a positive answer to the question) has now been pointed out.